# Using FlexLayout the content collapses instead of shrinking and covering the available width

Tags: html, css, apexcharts

Am Using Angular and the flex Layout to create a dashboard, each time to I open the navigation, the items don't shrink as expected and end up pushing the last to the next line.I have the parent component HTML to be

```html
<div
class="cards-section"
fxLayout="row wrap"
fxLayout.lt-sm="column"
fxLayoutAlign="flex-start"
fxLayoutGap="32px"
>
```

[image: photo_1]

Component HTML is

```html
<app-dashboard-chart
  class="chart-bg bar-chart"
  fxFlex="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
  fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)"
  fxFlex.lt-sm="100%"
  >
```

It breaks to the next line as shown below, am using apex charts for the charts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component in fxLayout try to replace "wrap" with "nowrap"

Comment: The items are not shrinking...though it's now not going to the next line as before

Comment: Can this be a problem with the charts having a fixed size because  the card above shrink uniformly

Comment: Yes, it can be. Can you use a percentage for the size of the charts and maybe you can make them go to next line when they become too small.